# Anything inside <> in RDLC is being omitted

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I am using a text box :
 Expression inside it holds value:

```
<b>Name1</b><br>
  Description 1..Hi this is 1 <br>
<b>Name2</b><br>
  Description 2...Hi from <email.com> <br>
```

I am using option : **HTML-Interpret HTML tags as styles** as I need formatting. 
I am unable to get  **"email.com"** as it is in <> tags.
But I need to display the email in <> tags. I am unable to separate the content in different boxes, because it is dynamically generated. 
It can have any Name1 Description1....Name(n) Description(n) based on users input

Any suggestion How I can deal with this?

Comment: And there's no way to remove the <> from the email.com in order to turn this into valid html? Or, you know, change them to &lt; &gt;?

Comment: User copy pastes the content directly from forwaded message from outlook.Which has this tag <> for email. And there are a couple of emails so removing from all can be tedious and time consuming.